# Unknown Error Parsing Lead Query

Tags: soql

When I try to run the below query in the developer console, I am getting the error message:

> Unknown error parsing query

What could cause this exception with the below query?

```
SELECT Name, AccountLookup__r.OwnerId, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE (OwnerId <> AccountLookup__r.OwnerId)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187460&type=1):

> Salesforce does not allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL query.
>
> To achieve this you may create a formula field that will compare fields and return a value (like true or false) which you may use in a WHERE clause.
>
> So for the above query, you could create a formula field on User object with return type Text e.g. NameCompare, with the formula
>
> ```
> IF(User.FirstName != User.LastName, 'true', 'false')
> ```
>
> Now our query will be:
>
> ```
> List<User> Users = [SELECT id, name FROM User where NameCompare= 'true'];
> ```
>
> Following idea has been posted on ideaexchange portal for allowing field-to-field comparison in SOQL:
> https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0

You could simplify/clean up the above approach by using a checkbox formula:

```
User.FirstName != User.LastName
```

Which would change the query to:

```
List<User> lstUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE NameCompare = true];
```